# Why can't I get cookies from ngrok using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm trying to parse cookies from the client to the server using node js. Everything works fine, but when I switch from localhost to an ngrok url, cookies are not parsed. Actually every time I call req.cookies["username"] I get undefined as a response from the server.

This is the important part from my ap.js:

```
app.ws('/', function(ws, req, res) {
console.log(req.cookies["username"]) });
```

Although, I don't think that this is a coding problem. I've installed every dependency and as I said cookie is successfully sent from client to server on localhost but not when I start ngrok. Something must be wrong with the random ngrok subdomain or/and with the ngrok server. I've tried Chrome and Firefox. Both have the same issue.

I have windows 7 64bit using node js v10.22.0.

Comment: I'm having troubles parsing the 1st sentence:
> I'm trying to parse cookies from the client to the server using node js.

Comment: I mean that I'm trying to get a cookie using node js. The client stores some cookies on his browser and then the server (ap.js) "gets" them. After that, the server send information back to the client.

Comment: Have you tried some alternative to ngrok? like localtunnel?

Comment: I've tried localtunnel, but I'm just waiting. This is what I write in cmd: lt --port 80    Is it down?

Comment: Seems so, https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/343

Comment: Did you set the cookies when you were on the ngrok url or localhost?

Comment: I set the cookies on ngrok.

Comment: I tried it on localhost.run too. Same issue.

Comment: Update: It seems that I fixed it. I tried to add 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and I couldn't get the cookies. The conclusion I had was that ngrok was not the fault. I forgot to change ws://localhost:5001 from my index.php to ws://127.0.0.1:5001. It worked with 127.0.0.1, but not with ngrok. I tried it with my IPv4 address and it worked. The problem with ngrok is that if I want to have 2 ports I'll have to create 2 different subdomains. I need 1 subdomain that will have 2 ports (example.ngrok.io:80, example.ngrok.io:5001). Do you know if that's possible? If not, is it with localhost.run?